# AWS Appsync mutation feature used in an android app, fails to insert data into DynamoDB

Tags: android, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I created an android application that is intended to work with the AWS Amplify library with the help of following links specified,
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1/ and https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#delta-sync. 
By following the documents I was able to create the project correctly, and with the use of AWS Amplify CLI  I was able to set up the Auth Cognito,API,Storage and Lambda functions. I also confirmed using the AWS amplify web console that a DynamoDB, Lambda function (and index.js file) and an API for the project has got created.

Issue:
**No data gets inserted in the dynamodb when I try to write data into the DB programmatically via mutation**(an aws appsync feature).

Following is the code that I have used to achieve the task.

```
 private void save() {
        final String name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt_name)).getText().toString();
        final String description = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_description)).getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(AddPetActivity.this, "inside save()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        CreatePetInput input = CreatePetInput.builder()
                .name(name)
                .description(description)
                .build();

        CreatePetMutation addPetMutation = CreatePetMutation.builder()
                .input(input)
                .build();
        ClientFactory.appSyncClient().mutate(addPetMutation).enqueue(mutateCallback);
    }

    // Mutation callback code
    private GraphQLCall.Callback<CreatePetMutation.Data> mutateCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<CreatePetMutation.Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull final Response<CreatePetMutation.Data> response) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successful in AddPetMutation");
                    Toast.makeText(AddPetActivity.this, "Added pet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AddPetActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
```

On running the app and executing the save function I get the following log (this is mainly the library log):

```
2019-11-27 19:04:40.559 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:04:40.560 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:04:40.560 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to process next mutation if one exists.
2019-11-27 19:04:40.562 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]:Persistent mutations queue is EMPTY!. Will check inMemory Queue next
2019-11-27 19:04:40.562 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]: In Memory mutations queue was EMPTY!. Nothing to process, exiting
2019-11-27 19:04:45.151 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Processing mutation.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.151 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[2]: First, checking if it is a retry of mutation that encountered a conflict.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.151 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[2]:Nope, hasn't encountered  conflict
2019-11-27 19:04:45.157 16532-16532/gadgeon.pro4tech.com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:  Added mutation[1cb07050-1166-49e9-9297-cf84f411b64e] to inMemory Queue
2019-11-27 19:04:45.157 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/S3ObjectManagerImplementation: Thread:[2]: Looking at Key [input] of type [CreatePetInput]
2019-11-27 19:04:45.167 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:addPersistentMutationObject: Adding mutation[1cb07050-1166-49e9-9297-cf84f411b64e]: CreatePetMutation 
    {"query":"mutation CreatePet($input: CreatePetInput!) {  createPet(input: $input) {    __typename    id    name    description  }}","variables":{"input":{"name":"dog","description":"nice dog"}}}
2019-11-27 19:04:45.185 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Added mutation[1cb07050-1166-49e9-9297-cf84f411b64e] to Persistent Queue. No S3 Objects found
2019-11-27 19:04:45.185 16532-16532/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Created both in-memory and persistent records. Now going to signal queue handler.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.185 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.185 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to process next mutation if one exists.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.187 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]:Persistent mutations queue is EMPTY!. Will check inMemory Queue next
2019-11-27 19:04:45.187 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Setting mutationInProgress as true.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.187 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]: Processing next from in Memory queue
2019-11-27 19:04:45.187 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/InMemoryOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]:Executing mutation [1cb07050-1166-49e9-9297-cf84f411b64e]
2019-11-27 19:04:45.187 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/InMemoryOfflineMutationObject: Thread:[12047]: Executing mutation by proceeding with the chain.
2019-11-27 19:04:45.187 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/S3ObjectManagerImplementation: Thread:[12047]: Looking at Key [input] of type [CreatePetInput]
2019-11-27 19:04:45.188 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncComplexObjectsInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: No s3 Objects found. Proceeding with the chain
2019-11-27 19:04:45.199 16532-21832/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/InterceptorCallback: Thread:[12081]: onFetch()
2019-11-27 19:04:50.567 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:04:50.568 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:05:00.576 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:05:00.577 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:05:10.587 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:05:10.588 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:05:20.596 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:05:20.596 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:05:30.598 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:05:30.598 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:05:40.608 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:05:40.608 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:05:50.616 16532-16652/awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:05:50.616 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:06:00.627 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:06:00.627 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:06:10.636 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:06:10.637 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:06:20.642 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:06:20.643 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:06:30.645 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:06:30.646 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:06:40.653 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:06:40.653 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:06:50.662 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:06:50.663 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:07:00.666 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:07:00.666 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:07:10.670 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:07:10.670 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:07:20.679 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:07:20.680 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:07:30.691 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:07:30.691 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:07:40.699 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:07:40.700 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:07:50.711 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:07:50.711 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:08:00.719 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:08:00.719 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:08:10.723 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:08:10.724 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:08:20.734 16532-16652/gadgeon.pro4tech.com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:08:20.735 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:08:30.742 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:08:30.742 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:08:40.753 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:08:40.754 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:08:50.763 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:08:50.763 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:00.774 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:09:00.774 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:10.784 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:09:10.784 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:20.799 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:09:20.799 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:30.809 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:09:30.810 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:40.820 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:09:40.821 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:50.829 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:09:50.830 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:50.830 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Dispose called
2019-11-27 19:09:50.831 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: Dispose called for mutation [com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.CreatePetMutation@e3b6457].
2019-11-27 19:09:50.831 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]: Handling cancellation for mutation [com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.CreatePetMutation@e3b6457]
2019-11-27 19:09:50.831 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]: Mutation being canceled is the one currently in progress. Handling it 
2019-11-27 19:09:50.831 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]:Removing mutation [1cb07050-1166-49e9-9297-cf84f411b64e] from persistent store
2019-11-27 19:09:50.858 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Setting mutationInProgress as false.
2019-11-27 19:09:50.859 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:09:50.859 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to process next mutation if one exists.
2019-11-27 19:09:50.861 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]:Persistent mutations queue is EMPTY!. Will check inMemory Queue next
2019-11-27 19:09:50.861 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]: In Memory mutations queue was EMPTY!. Nothing to process, exiting
2019-11-27 19:10:00.840 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[12047]: processing Mutations
2019-11-27 19:10:00.840 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-11-27 19:10:00.840 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[12047]: Got message to process next mutation if one exists.
2019-11-27 19:10:00.841 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]:Persistent mutations queue is EMPTY!. Will check inMemory Queue next
2019-11-27 19:10:00.841 16532-16652/com.awsamplifypoc3 V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[12047]: In Memory mutations queue was EMPTY!. Nothing to process, exiting
```

from the logs it is clear that the library receives our data and created both in-memory and persistent records but later by itself calls Dispose and cancels the mutation and removes it and the mutation callback is never hit and the application remains idle at that point.

FYI:
Added the following schema in the graphQL.schema file

type Pet @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}

In the  **project‘s** build.gradle I have added the following dependency.

```
classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:2.9.+'
```

and in **app's** build.gradle I have added a plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
```

and the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.8.+'
```

Please help me know how I can overcome this issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend adding a Log statement in onResponse before running the response handler on the UI thread and also adding a log statement in onError callback to see if there are any errors reported. Commonly reported errors include authorization error where a valid authorization token is not included.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan, this was exactly the problem, I had identified the issue and solved the same. Anyway thanks for your support.

Comment: can you post the solution and root cause so it will help others?